# Size of an amah (אמה)

Tags: shiurim-measurements, hands-fingers, eggs

One of the our measurements is the אמה ("cubit"), for which the most usual value is 24 אצבעות. My question is, **What information do we have from earlier sources (Rishon or Acharon, say, before the Tzelach) on how an amah is measured for a person? Do they describe where exactly on the body it begins and ends?**
I know that estimates for an amah vary from 18 inches to 24 inches, maybe, and unless people changed a *lot* in size in two thousand years it seems like those must correspond to measuring different places in the body. I think.

Comment: Most calculators (ie people who calculate and publish a full set of measurements) pick one as a base unit, measure it precisely, and derive all the others. A large difference in published amma values is probably due to extrapolation from a slightly different base value.

Comment: It could be I should just remove the entire prelude and just ask my question. I've bolded it.

Comment: I was responding to "those must correspond to measuring different places in the body"

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%94_(%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94)

Comment: I looked there, Fred. Did you see an answer to my question? Note that I asked for a source, Rishon or Acharon.

Comment: K'subos 5b: "אצבעותיו של אדם ...דמחלקן כל חדא וחדא למילתיה עבידא דאמר מר זו זרת זו קמיצה זו אמה זו אצבע זה גודל". Rashi: "זו אמה. מהגדולה מודדין אמת בנין ואמת כלים:". Rabbeinu Bechaye, Vayikra 8:23: "וכך סדור חמשה אצבעות היד בשמותיהן והם אצבע אמה קמיצה גודל זרת... שלישי לו נקרא אמה והוא האמצעי וארוך מכולן ואמת הזרוע נשלמה בו". Magen Avraham OC 349:2: "באמה שלו: היינו הזרוע". Radak (Y'chezkeil 41:8): "שאר האמות הם מן ראש האצבע הנקרא אמה עד פרק המבדיל בין הזרוע והקנה". Ram"a' MiFano (Shu"t 3): "שאמה סתם של בנין אינה אלא ששה טפחים והיא מפרק הזרוע עד סוף אצבע אמצעית דהיינו אצבע צרדא דאמה קרינן לה"

Comment: Also see Rash (אהלות, [mishna 1:8, s.v. "*Sh'nayim bakaneh*"](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%97#%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F)): "עצם המחובר ליד מלשון (יחזקאל מ) וּקְנֵה הַמִּדָּה שבו מודדין האמה". || I don't think this elbow-to-fingertip definition of a cubit is a big *chiddush*, however; I was under the impression that this was a well known measurement since the Bronze Age. @MichoelR

Comment: @Fred Excellent. I also thought it was well-known. I asked because I thought someone must be using a different measurement, if they're going to get to 22 inches or whatever. People vary a lot in finger-width, but is there anyone with a cubit that long?

Comment: We can discuss how exactly to measure a finger-width, but it sounds like you're saying that measure an amah is going to be much more clear.

Comment: @MichoelR Well, there is an interesting remark by [R' Emanuel Chai Riki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Hai_Ricchi) in [*Chosheiv Machashavos* (מקוה טהרה, chapter 22)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7141&pgnum=21), where he seems to say the *amah* extends all the way to the armpit (cf. Radak ibid., mentioning an interpretation that the *amos* described in that verse in *Y'chezkeil* are a different type and extend to the armpit: "ויש מפרשים מן תחת אצילות ידיך שהוא בית השחי כי שאר האמות הם מן ראש האצבע הנקרא אמה עד פרק המבדיל בין הזרוע והקנה ואלו היו אמות מגיעות עד בית השחי").

Comment: @Fred Huh, thanks Fred! Could you move your answer to Answers?